# Which OAuth 2.0 flow for secure REST API used by SPA.

Tags: rest, oauth

I have implemented an api that my SPA front-end will use. Now I want to secure the endpoints of the API using OAuth 2.0. The SPA will be used by hundreds (possible thousands) of registered and logged in users. 
Which OAuth 2.0 grant type flow should I use?

FWIW I am using spring boot for the backend and angular for the frontend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Implicit Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.2) is optimised for Single Page Applications.
It allows a token to be obtained in one call to an `authorize` endpoint.

Note that you will not be able to obtain a refresh token for offline / long-lived access to the API with the Implicit grant.

Comment: Thanks iandyman. I ended up using auth0 for securing my REST API as well as for authentication.